# CompletableFuture - orTimeout

Tags: java

What is the advantage of using the `orTimeout` and `get` instead of just `get`?

```
CompletableFuture<T> cf = ....;

cf.orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get()
```

over

```
cf.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I think the main advantage is not holding the thread in case request is taking longer then expected. `get` will wait till response comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the source, I see that `orTimeout` cancels the CompletableFuture after the timeout whereas `get` does not cancel.

```
public CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    if (unit == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (result == null)
        whenComplete(new Canceller(Delayer.delay(new Timeout(this),
                                                 timeout, unit)));
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`orTimeout` returns a new `CompletableFuture`, and it can be applied in a chain or at some other lower level than the final consumer:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class ResourceLimiter implements ServiceApi {
  ServiceApi delegate;

  @Override
  CompletableFuture<Result> findResult(ServiceInput input) {
    return delegate.findResult(input).orTimeout(10, SECONDS);
  }
}


@AllArgsConstructor
class IHaveLotsOfTime {
  ServiceApi service;

  void checkResultsSlowly() {
    service.get(12, HOURS);
  }
}
```